# How to log authenticated user information using morgan?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, request-headers, morgan

I am using `next-auth` with my React.JS / Next.JS application using morgan. How do I log authenticated user? `User: ':remote-user',` doesn't give me anything at all. If I could set the req header, how do I retrieve and log it at the server using `User: ':req[header]',`?